# Is it a bad practice to provide a Laravel external OAuth services without a local one?

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-socialite

I want to provide an OAuth login services (Google, Facebook, Twitter) in my website without a local registration/login forms to reduce the complexity of getting the user full name & country from the local form, Is this a bad practice?